# Wrapping function call in Task.async causes weird behaviour that I do not understand

Tags: elixir, httpoison

Consider following snippets of code:

a)

```
IO.puts "test1"
task = Task.async fn ->
  Foo.Bar.send_file_for_processing(file_url)
end
IO.puts "test2"
content = Task.await(task)
IO.puts "test4"
```

b)

```
IO.puts "test1"
content = Foo.Bar.send_file_for_processing(file_url)
IO.puts "test2"
```

and in Foo.Bar module:

```
def send_file_for_processing(file_url) do
  json = file_url |> encoded_file |> request_json
  IO.puts "test3"
  request = HTTPoison.post(
    @processing_endpoint,
    json,
    @headers,
    params: %{"key": @api_key}, connect_timeout: 100000, recv_timeout: 100000, timeout: 100000
  )
  IO.puts "test5"

  (...)
end
```

When I use code snippet a), the "test5" is never reached, as if the program would hang during HTTPoison POST request. It just never finishes. Meanwhile, with snippet b), the HTTPoison POST request completes normally and without any delays.

To be honest, debugging this made me lose some time and I still do not understand the problem with the snippet a). Am I misusing the Task module? I have checked the documentation and could not find anything that would explain this issue to me.

EDIT:
Output for snippet a)

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Comment: You have 2 `"test3"` debug output, would you mind to change either of them and confirm the task is printing a line _before_ HTTPoison request?

Comment: @mudasobwa done

Comment: @PawełDuda can you try to create a minimal reproducible example that shows this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see you have high timeout values for the HTTP request. The task has a default timeout value of `5_000 ms`, so it's very possible that the task timeouts before the request is finished. Subsequently the task is killed and you never see the output. The `Task.await/2` function accepts the timeout as the second argument.

Regardless of that you should be seeing a task timeout errors. Perhaps you're ignoring some output?

Comment: I really wish that it was the case here but the task does not seem to be timing out... Even if something takes longer than 5 seconds, it eventually finishes properly. Besides, in case of timeout the program should continue past `Task.await` and print "test4" which doesn't happen :/

Comment: Both those things aren't true. After the timeout passes the task is killed, and the task process terminated immediately. Furthermore since the caller of `Task.async/1` is linked to the task, when the task times out in `Task.await/2` the process dies as well, so the "test4" should never appear.

Comment: You were right. I increased the timeout to `100_000` and now it appears to  behave correctly :) Thank you, I would surely have spent a lot more time tracking this.